# Numeric Keyboard?

Tags: windows-phone-7, keyboard, numerical

I have several instances in my application that I would prefer to use a numerical keyboard. Does one exist in WP7 and if so, how would I go about popping that one up for a text box instead of the normal one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use InputScope for the textBox

```
<TextBox Name="myTextBox" InputScope="Digits"/>
```

Here is the full list of InputScopes that are expected to be supported, based on the current enum names for InputScopeNameValue:

[NOTE] Even if you don't get the keyboard you want, you can still use it because it is highly possible to be supported in the future (final Mango probably)

http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/07/06/WP7-InputScope.aspx

1. AddressCity
2. AddressCountryName
3. AddressCountryShortName
4. AddressStateOrProvince
5. AddressStreet
6. AlphanumericFullWidth
7. AlphanumericHalfWidth
8. ApplicationEnd
9. Bopomofo
10. Chat
11. CurrencyAmount
12. CurrencyAmountAndSymbol
13. CurrencyChinese
14. Date
15. DateDay
16. DateDayName
17. DateMonth
18. DateMonthName
19. DateYear
20. Default
21. Digits
22. EmailNameOrAddress
23. EmailSmtpAddress
24. EmailUserName
25. EnumString
26. FileName
27. FullFilePath
28. Hanja
29. Hiragana
30. KatakanaFullWidth
31. KatakanaHalfWidth
32. LogOnName
33. Maps
34. NameOrPhoneNumber
35. Number
36. NumberFullWidth
37. OneChar
38. Password
39. PersonalFullName
40. PersonalGivenName
41. PersonalMiddleName
42. PersonalNamePrefix
43. PersonalNameSuffix
44. PersonalSurname
45. PhraseList
46. PostalAddress
47. PostalCode
48. Private
49. RegularExpression
50. Search
51. Srgs
52. TelephoneAreaCode
53. TelephoneCountryCode
54. TelephoneLocalNumber
55. TelephoneNumber
56. Text
57. Time
58. TimeHour
59. TimeMinorSec
60. Url
61. Xml
62. Yomi